# I have no idea how to solve the question... Can someone please explain the solution

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a,b,c,d$ be distinct non-zero real numbers with $a+b=c+d$. Find the eigenvalues of the matrix

$$M=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&1\\
c&d&1\\
1&-1&0\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What have you tried? Where does this problem come from? What difficulties did you face?

Comment: I have found the characteristic equation but am not and to solve it

Comment: Hint: what happens when you multiply $M$ by $(1 1 0)$?  This gives one of the 3 eigenvalues, which should help in factoring the characteristic equation.

Comment: @dxiv Do you mean $0$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: @ErickWong Right, of course. I removed my previous comment, it was a mental typo.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be that $3\times3$ matrix and $\lambda=a+b=c+d$.

The vector $(1,1,0)$ is an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

It remains to find two other eigenvalues $\mu$ and $\nu$.

We know that $\lambda+\mu+\nu=tr(M)=a+d$ and $\lambda\mu\nu=\det(M)$

This should give the solution ...

Comment: The matrix is singular so another eigenvalue is easy to obtain.

Comment: @ErickWong: that's true, 0 is an eigenvalue. But what if $a+b=c+d=0$ ?

Comment: Yeah, then I guess $\det(M)$ doesn't yield enough information since $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution..... I have got a+b as an eigen value is there any way to check if it's correct

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is easy to compute. I get $P(x)=-x(x+b-d)(x-a-b)$. So, it is correct to say that $a+b$ is an eigenvalue.